# iOS 7 Simulator showing screen but not phone

Tags: ios-simulator, ios7

Installed Xcode 5 and compiled my app to use iOS 7. However when I run the simulator it only shows the screen of the phone and not the complete phone e.g. the phone body with the home button. Can continue developing my app but would like to understand where I am going wrong. Grateful for any help.

Comment: Nothing wrong. The frame is relatively useless and so its not visible with every configuration. Command + Shift + H = Homebutton

Comment: @MatthiasBauch The frame is very useful if you are making an image of what the app looks like on the phone...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Retina Versions of the iOS Simulator iPhone does no longer have the iPhone frame, which is kind of sad.

The only way to have the frame back is to run the App in iOS 6.1 mode of the non-Retina iPhone. But I guess, that does not make much sense...

Comment: Thanks everybody for answering my question and some useful tips.

Answer (score 5):

When active simulator device and then select this option

`window -> Show Device Bezels`

- simulator without frame
  [image: simulator without frame]
- simulator with frame
  [image: simulator with frame]

Answer (score 3):

In iOS Simulator, `Go to Window -> Scale -> 100%` or `Command-1`.

You can adjust the scale size as you wish using `Command-2` for 75% and `Command-3` for 50%

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue. (Yes, I realize you wrote this comment over a year ago. I'm just now experiencing this issue, and this thread popped up.)

Answer (score 2):

I lost the iphone frame on the simulator after I plugged into a projector.  After messing around with the display settings, I finally was able to restore the iphone frame:

Go to System Preferences -> display and set it to scaled, More Space.  Now in your iOS simulator, set the scale to 100% (CMD+1).

Hope that works for you too.

Answer (score 2):

I think you guys need the iPhone frame to press the home button/close background tasks in simulator.

Use   Cmd key+shift+H for **Home button operation**

Use   Cmd Key+ shift+H(press H twice holding window and shift) **Displays list of background tasks**

Comment: When speaking of "Window key" you probably mean `cmd` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the latest XCode build?

In the first Beta-version of Xcode 5, the simulator use to not show the external iPhone frame.

Comment: I downloaded the latest version today.